# Accepting a host key on the device and the workstation

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, android, vmware

I am trying to install the Ubuntu touch on my Samsung Galaxy Nexus running android 4.3. However, I am having problems understanding how to accept the host key on my device, and what exactly the workstation is and where I can get it.

'On either Android version you must then enable USB debugging via Settings > Developer options > USB debugging. You will also need to accept a host key on the device.
On the workstation-> adb kill-server; adb start-server'

This is the step I am having problems with. I have enabled USB debbuging but I don't know how to do the rest. Can you please give me step by step instructions, because I am a newbie to all this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workstation here refers to the computer you're using to install Ubuntu on the phone. When you connect the phone to the computer and try to access it via adb (`adb shell`), the phone automatically asks you if it should allow the computer to connect (and displays a key (looks like: 00:11:AA:....)). [image: Tap OK and you're done with this stage.]

Comment: When getting the _Allow USB debugging? The computer's RSA key fingerprint is:_ is possible to check with `cut -d" " -f1 adbkey.pub | openssl base64 -A -d -a | openssl md5 -c` (in my case was in `~/snap/scrcpy/166/.android/`, I was using scrcpy).